# firebaseAuth with new angularfire .5 returns undefined

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Ok. I have a working app using .4 of angularfire but decided to make the jump to .5 but I can not even get the basic auth to work.  I get undefined returned from firebaseAuth and I am not making the mistakes that caused similar issues in prior question.  I have created a plunker that tries to authenticate using public data set.  It returns undefined.

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2I0Q95FoYLAOGqxSDM2M?p=preview

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Its very few lines of code and follows the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok.  I know it is .5 and doc's are not yet complete...but...no where does it mention that firebase-simple-login.js is REQUIRED regardless of whether or not you are using simple login.  The reason my code returns undefined is because of that dependency.  In my plunker uncomment the inclusion of that script and firebaseAuth works as advertised.  

So please update the docs so no one else makes this step 1 mistake.  

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is great feedback and we'll update the docs as soon as possible.

Comment: @EricG you can answer your own question, so others know it's been resolved. Cheers.

Comment: No enough reputation points.  Can only answer after six hours ( or something like that).

Comment: I'm having some trouble here as well - getting some errors regarding `createUser` undefined.  Probably will post a separate question.